# Python unittest of a module performing ioctl system calls

Tags: python, linux, python-unittest, ioctl

I need to write unit test for a python module that mainly performs ioclt system calls to talk to a linux driver. Ideally I should be able to run the tests on any hardware platform, but in this case the link between the module and the hardware looks very tight.
My question is: how can I stub the interface to the Linux OS? And also: does it make any sense to write this kind of unit test?

Thanks in advance!